# How do I find glibc.so on linux distro to dynamically load it

Tags: linux, dart, glibc, ffi, dynamic-loading

I'm trying to dynamically load glibc under ubuntu (and ideally other linux distros).

The aim is to  call seteuid.

I'm not certain what the correct method is to identify the path.

When running a find command I don't even see glib.so but I do see lib.so.

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so

Is this the correct file?

If it is the correct file what is the correct way if find it on any system (hardcoding the path would be a last resort).

Statically linking isn't an option as I'm calling the method from Dart using ffi.

Comment: The dynamic linker [knows where to look](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux), so you should simply link against `libc.so` without a path.

Comment: @Thomas, the dynamic linker needs the soname, that's `libc.so.6` on most glibc targets.

Comment: @BrettSutton I don't think the Dart language runtime is compatible with calling `seteuid`. Even a minimal program creates multiple threads, and calling `seteuid` affects all of them. The Dart runtime does not expect that.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I've not seen a problem 'so far' but I've only ran a small no of tests. Certainly if a user starts another isolate and do any file io they are going to get some problematic results. As to the dart vm I suspect that it never writes to any files so I think the native threads won't actually be a problem.  My use case is a dart project I'm building https://pub.dev/packages/dcli. The intent of dcli is to replace bash :D. So the classic use isn't going to be a problem. I'm already running dart under sudo and my intent is to reduce privlidges when not needed.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer:

var path = 'libc.so.6';

Looks like its on the path and contains the seteuid method.

This is the final code I ended up with:

```dart
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

import 'package:dcli/dcli.dart';


// on systems with _POSIX_SAVED_IDS defined
typedef setEffectiveUID_func = Int32 Function(Uint32 effectiveUID);
typedef setEffectiveUID = int Function(int effectiveUID);

/// on other systems.
/// sets the effective and real uids.
typedef setUID_func = Int32 Function(Uint32 realUID, Uint32 effectiveUID);
typedef setUID = int Function(int realUID, int effectiveUID);


class Priviliges {
  static final Priviliges _self = Priviliges._internal();

  DynamicLibrary dylib;

  // the logged in user's original UID
  int userUID;

  /// true if we are running under sudo.
  bool sudo;

  /// I'm confused.
  int realUID;

  /// The user's effective UID when the script started.
  /// If they are running as sudo then this will be root.
  int originalEffectiveUID;

  /// Used to track what UID is currently in effect.
  int currentEffectiveUID;

  factory Priviliges() => _self;

  Priviliges._internal() {
    var path = 'libc.so.6';
    if (Platform.isMacOS) path = '/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib';
    if (Platform.isWindows) path = r'primitives_library\Debug\primitives.dll';
    dylib = DynamicLibrary.open(path);

    realUID = _realUID;

    var sudo_uid = env['SUDO_UID'];
    if (sudo_uid != null) {
      sudo = true;
      userUID = int.tryParse(sudo_uid);
    } else {
      /// we aren't running sudo
      sudo = false;
      userUID = realUID;
    }

    originalEffectiveUID = _effectiveUID;
    currentEffectiveUID = originalEffectiveUID;
  }


  int get _effectiveUID {
    final geteuidPointer =
        dylib.lookup<NativeFunction<getEffectiveUID_func>>('geteuid');
    final geteuid = geteuidPointer.asFunction<getEffectiveUID>();
    var uid = geteuid();

    print('get effiective guid=$uid');
    return uid;
  }

  set _effectiveUID(int effectiveUID) {
    print('setting effective to $effectiveUID');
    var result = -1;
    try {
      final seteuidPointer =
          dylib.lookup<NativeFunction<setEffectiveUID_func>>('seteuid');
      final seteuid = seteuidPointer.asFunction<setEffectiveUID>();

      print(blue('settting effectiveUID =$effectiveUID'));
      result = seteuid(effectiveUID);
    } on ArgumentError catch (_) {
      // seteuid isn't available so lets try setreuid

      final setreuidPointer =
          dylib.lookup<NativeFunction<setUID_func>>('setreuid');
      final setreuid = setreuidPointer.asFunction<setUID>();
      result = setreuid(-1, effectiveUID);
    }

    if (result != 0) {
      throw PriviligesException('Unable to set the Effective UID: $result');
    }
  }
}

class PriviligesException extends DCliException {
  PriviligesException(String message) : super(message);
}
```

Comment: "I'm trying to dynamically load glibc " you appear to have http://xyproblem.info/. If you are on GLIBC-based system, `libc.so.6` is *already* loaded into your process, and you don't need to load it again (nor would doing so actually work).

Comment: I'm using Dart's ffi and it must know how to do this as the library loaded as expected.